Reflect x-axis (mirror screen) on Linux tty without GUI and without xrandr -x

I want to run old computers without GUI.
If I use the command xrandr -x in a Linux system (with GUI),
the whole screen is reflected (mirrored) around the Y-axis
(along the X-axis). 
So text is mirror-text, like:
pod
        changes to
                           boq
and LED/6
      changes to (something like)
                    ∂ \⫏∃⌋
(but by actually reflecting the characters,
not substituting similar-looking ones).
Even the layout is reflected like a mirror would be on the right or left side of the display, and you would watch into the mirror. 
I use my computer this way, so also reading not from left to right. 
I read text inverted from right to left. 
The letters are each themselves mirrored.
Without graphical user interface, I can't use xrandr -x. 
So I am searching for a command that inverts the whole screen to x-axis timeless in the tty, so I can read text and use commands mirrored. 
Text always starts from the right side of the screen. 
It is like Arabic is written, but with Latin/Roman letters
and other characters normally displayable in the console/terminal.

Please describe in plain language what you want to accomplish.  For example, do you mean that you want text to scroll down, with output appearing above the command that generated it?  Or do you mean that you want text to appear right-to-left?  Do you want cat to appear as tac, or do you also want characters to appear as mirror images?  … … … … … …  Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

OK, thanks for that.  But I asked whether you wanted letters simply to appear in reverse order, or to appear as mirror images, and you said you want “ow” to change to “wo”.  Those are two of the least illustrative letters you could have chosen (along with ‘l’, ‘v’, ‘x’, ‘A’, ‘H’, ‘I’, ‘M’, ‘T’, ‘U’, and ‘Y’).  … … … … … … … …  That said, while I don’t know for sure, I’d be surprised if you can do this with Linux in general.  It might be possible at the graphics card level.  Can you provide information about the graphics hardware on the computer(s) where you want to do this?

I don't want those characters just to appear in reverse order, I want them as mirror images. Sorry for using "wo" and "ow", you're right, that it doesen't make it clear enough, maybe this works: "p" should look like "q", and "d" should look like "b". And to be clear again about the orientation: Every sentence or line always starts not on the left side of the screen like usually, it shall start on the right side and the mirrorerd characters one after the other placed to the left side. I use an Intel HD graphics 520 on one computer. Is this enough information about the graphics hardware?

Well, as I said, you’ve gotten outside my area of expertise.  I guess that might be enough for somebody else to be able to answer, but please [edit] it into the question.   And review my changes.  (I removed your reference to “windows”, since, as I understand it, you’re talking about running Linux without a window system.)

I don't think there's a ready-to-use solution for this. "Without GUI" could mean the console is using the ancient VGA text mode which I highly doubt has such a feature, or could mean the framebuffer whose options are listed in the Linux kernel's fbcon.rst file including rotation by 90/180/270 degrees but not a single word about mirroring.

My biggest question, though, is: Why? Why do you need this feature at all in the first place? And why do you need to go without GUI; I mean how extremely old those computers are if you cannot fire up an X Window system with a simple window manager and a lightweight graphical terminal emulator?

The main reason is a personal one. I am fine by mirroring my text with the command for the X Window system. But I want to learn more about the Linux-System at a lower(without GUI) level, and want learn to modify configurations. And this task is something really special to me, which motivates me a lot. A second is: One of mine machines takes much longer time to startx, it is very slow. Maybe I will get also an rapberry pi.   I am not sure, wether I annoy somebody here with my own personal feelings(I thaught, this should not be here in the comment section). If so, let me know.

Sorry if my question came across as annoyance, I didn't mean that way, but I was really curious, it's not typical for someone to have an extremely unusual request and not be satisfied with the most obvious approach. As for your system being "very slow", whatever that means: try a corresponding OS. startx was fast for me 25 years ago, and it also was maybe ~20 years ago when xranrdr appeared. Distros need more and more resources over time, go with a distro roughly from the era of your hardware, not a much newer one.

If you really wish to experiment and learn, and you're not afraid of touching a kernel driver and extending its source code, I guess that based on the rotating code of the framebuffer driver it shouldn't be that hard to add mirroring there, too.

I feel being very different in my perspective how to look at this type of problem. I am very happy for your comments, every single sentence of them, (and the one before you). I will make my best out of your infos, even if it will take a lot of time. Have a nice day and night.
